# Summation and product term expressed in Mathematica

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, expression-construction, products

I have the following term which I would like to express correctly in Mathematica:

$$\sum_{i=1}^{m}\frac{1}{\prod_{j=1,j\neq i}^m(\rho_i-\rho_j)}$$

This means that for $m=3$ for example you should get the following

$$
\frac{1}{(\rho_1-\rho_2)(\rho_1-\rho_3)}+\frac{1}{(\rho_2-\rho_1)(\rho_2-\rho_3)}+\frac{1}{(\rho_3-\rho_2)(\rho_3-\rho_1)}
$$

Can you please help?

Comment: There is no duplication since the other question does not have a sum and thus the $i$ is not well defined. I chose to put a new question instead of creating some confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f[m_Integer] := Sum[1/Product[(Subscript[\[Rho], i] - Subscript[\[Rho], j]),
    {j, Complement[Range[1, m], {i}]}], {i, m}]

f[3]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Chris Degnen this is easy to implement into my calculations.

Answer (score 2):

```
With[{m = 3},
  Sum[1/Product[ρ[i] - ρ[j], {j, DeleteCases[Range[m], i]}], {i, m}]]
```

> $$
> \frac{1}{(\rho (2)-\rho (1)) (\rho (2)-\rho (3))}+\frac{1}{(\rho (3)-\rho (1)) (\rho
>    (3)-\rho (2))}+\frac{1}{(\rho (1)-\rho (2)) (\rho (1)-\rho (3))}
> $$

Here I used `ρ[i]` instead of `Subscript[ρ,i]` because subscripts are a [pitfall for new users](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18395/26598).

Update: It's easier to use `Drop` instead of `DeleteCases`, as in @kglr's solution:

```
With[{m = 3}, 
  Sum[1/Product[ρ[i] - ρ[j], {j, Drop[Range[m], {i}]}], {i, m}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ClearAll[f1, f2]
f1[m_] := Module[{a = Array[ρ, m]}, m / 
  HarmonicMean @ MapIndexed[Apply[Times] @* Drop, Outer[Subtract, a, a]]

f2[m_] := Module[{a = Array[ρ, m]}, 
  m Moment[ MapIndexed[Apply[Times] @* Drop, Outer[Subtract, a, a], -1]]


f1[3]
```

[image]

```
f1[4]
```

[image]

```
And @@ (f1[#] == f2[#] & /@ Range[100])
```

> True